# Get pdf embedded image width using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextshrp in c# get the embedded image with (in pdf) to compare against the pdf page with to check how much area the image has covered in the pdf page.

But I'm getting the actual width of the embedded image in pixels. Is there any way I can get the embedded size?

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at the source code of my program

http://pdfebookcutter.codeplex.com/

in the paint function, there should be a function retrieving the size of the images.

Comment: i couldn't able to find the paint function. pls advice.